# Question about arithmetic binomial coefficient

Tags: nt.number-theory, binomial-coefficients, divisors-multiples

i have a question about the following assertion:

let $n,j,u $ positive integer satisfying

$ n \geq 5,$   $ 1\leq j \leq n-1$,$ \; n+1 \leq u \leq n+j$

let  $ d[n]:=\operatorname{lcm}[1,2,..,n]$ thus $u$  divide  $d[n] \cdot C_{n+j}^n$

I think I have found a proof using valuation p-adic of prime number appearing in $u$ but I would like have another proof... thanks for help

Comment: Some clarifying questions: Do you mean $d[n].C_{n+j}^n$ as the product of those two terms? The claim is that $u$ divides $d[n]\binom{n+j}{n}$?

Comment: Do you mind editing your question to show the proof you attempted?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90860/discussion-on-question-by-mamiladi-question-about-arithmetic-binomial-coefficien).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple proof of your divisibility relation. It suffices to show that
$$\frac{\mathrm{lcm}(1,2,\dots,n+j)}{\mathrm{lcm}(1,2,\dots,n)}\quad\text{divides}\quad\binom{n+j}{n}\quad\text{for}\quad 0\leq j\leq n.$$
That is, for any prime $p$ and for $0\leq j\leq n$, we have that
$$\lfloor\log_p(n+j)\rfloor-\lfloor\log_p(n)\rfloor\leq\sum_{k=1}^\infty
\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n+j}{p^k}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^k}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{j}{p^k}\right\rfloor\right).$$
Note that the terms on the right hand side are nonnegative integers. In addition, for $\lfloor\log_p(n)\rfloor<k\leq\lfloor\log_p(n+j)\rfloor$, the $k$-th term is positive, because in this case $n+j\geq p^k>n\geq j$. Hence the right hand side is at least the number of $k$'s satisfying $\lfloor\log_p(n)\rfloor<k\leq\lfloor\log_p(n+j)\rfloor$, and we are done.

Comment: yes!!,, it's better then considering cases thank you.

Comment: @mamiladi: If you like my answer, please accept it officially (so that it turns green). Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes i accepeted, tell me how to do ( for it turn to green)

Comment: i see share cite edit

Comment: it's done , thank you again.  I  have put another question about binomial identity....